# Intuitive reason for why $\int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \int_1^a \frac{1}{x} \, dx + \int_1^{b} \frac{1}{x} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, intuition

The natural logarithm is sometimes defined as a definite integral: $\displaystyle \ln a = \int_1^a \frac{1}{t} \, dt$. Since $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$, we have $\displaystyle \int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{t} \, dt = \displaystyle \int_1^{a} \frac{1}{t} \, dt + \displaystyle \int_1^{b} \frac{1}{t} \, dt$.

Is there an intuitive/geometric reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some hand-wavey intuition, which can be formalized with, say, substitution, or looking at partitions and upper or lower sums.

Subtract $\int_1^a\frac1tdt$ from both sides to get
$$
\int_a^{ab}\frac1tdt = \int_1^b\frac1tdt
$$
Why should this be true? If you move $a$ times further out along the $x$-axis, from $\int_1^b$ to $\int_a^{x}$, the graph is $a$ times closer to the $x$-axis, so you need to integrate over an $a$ times longer interval to get the same result. This would make $x = ab$.

Comment: Nice! Thinking in terms of $n$ rectangles with equal width as approximating the area under the graph, we get the following: going from the interval $[1, b]$ to $[a, ab]$ would result in multiplying each rectangle's width by $a$, and multiplying their heights by $1/a$. These two effects cancel out, thus the total area remains the same.

Comment: @twosigma Exactly. And since this holds for any partition, in particular it must hold in the limit when the partitions become infinitely fine, meaning the corresponding Riemann integrals are equal. This is one of the possible formalizations I mention.

Answer (score 3):

Split $$\int_1^{ab}\frac1xdx=\int_1^a\frac1xdx+\int_a^{ab}\frac1xdx$$

Call $ay=x$, then $a\,dy=dx$ and, of course, $\displaystyle\frac1x=\frac{1}{ay}$.

Notice that $x=a\Longrightarrow y=1$ and $x=ab\Longrightarrow y=b$

Hence $$\int_a^{ab}\frac1xdx=\int_1^b\frac{1}{ay}\, a\,dy=\int_1^b\frac1ydy$$

The geometrical intuition you are looking for comes from this geometrical property of the integral above. Indeed, recall $x=y$ and you easily get

$$\int_1^{ab}\frac1xdx=\int_1^a\frac1xdx+\int_1^{b}\frac1xdx$$