# When is volume invariant under constant multiples [$\int_X f = \int_{aX} f$]?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, functions

The function $f(x) = 1/x$ seems to have the property that $$\displaystyle \int_c^d \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \int_{ac}^{ad} \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$ (at least for positive $c, d$ and $a$). So if we move from the interval $[c, d]$ to $[ac, ad]$, the area under the graph hasn’t changed. [Intuitively this is because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669467/intuitive-reason-for-why-int-1ab-frac1x-dx-int-1a-frac1x) while widths were stretched by $a$, heights were shrunk by $1/a$, so the effects cancel out.

Is this an important property in general? Are there other (non-trivial) examples of this?

Edit: here's a casual musing: the natural log can be defined as the definite integral of $1/x$. Does the invariance of area under constant multiples relate to the fact that the exponential function doesn't change under taking derivatives?

Comment: Your example is a very particular case of a common situation studied in ergodic theory. See for instance https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolutely_continuous_invariant_measure